# Image path not found because of Angular routing in Rails with devise and paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, paperclip

I am using Angular along with Rails as an API and authentication is built with devise and an avatar added with paperclip.

Every route is routed through a catch all path in routes.rb to Angular app.js with $routeProvider.

All the templates are located inside Angular, except the navigation bar which is in Rails. I can successfully view the image of the user in the navbar:

```
<%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:thumb), class: 'img-circle' %>
```

The :avatar is mentioned like this in the user.rb model:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" },
    :default_url => "/images/default_user_avatar.jpg"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

The problem is that despite the default image is placed inside /images/ directory, it cannot be retrieved in order to be displayed. The link in the browser If I view the page source is website.com:3000/images/default_user_avatar.jpg and it doesn't exist.

I know I am missing serious code here but this issue is complicated, so please let me know what else could I include in order to get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you should be aware, *Rails* asset pipeline **precompiles** all assets and generates new filenames for them
(i.e. `assets/my-image-7e48a0e29e11ccae7aa9a0008b056933af9cb3ad347006f4bae0c5c7dab40277.png`)

There are three different ways in which you can get Angular to correctly load the images.

1. Add your images to the **public folder**. This will take your assets out of the *asset pipeline* and you will be able to reference them by their path and name.

   While this is by far the simplest solution, you should be well aware of the problems that the *asset pipeline* will not solve for you anymore.
2. For small size images, you can use their **encoded values in CSS**;
3. Use Rails **asset helpers** in your Angular files.

   - Add an `.erb` extension to your Angular files. It would be best if you use a single file that centralizes all assets URLs;
   - Use the Rails asset helper (`asset_path`, `image_path`, `image_url`, etc.) to get the correct asset path.

     For images found inside inside `app/assets/images`, you need to specify only the filename, without the `images/` part.

     `$scope.imageUrl = '<%= image_path("my-image.png") %>';`

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Actually the (1) way worked fine, but I am wondering If I am doing the right thing. I never touch the public folder for numerous reasons. The (2) even if it's a nice workaround, I would never choose it. Nice idea about the (3) too. Triggered my mind to think further !